# Python puzzle sets

Tags: python

I found this table in How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python.

```
1
2       4
3       6       9
4       8       12      16
5       10      15      20      25
6       12      18      24      30      36
7       14      21      28      35      42      49
```

The exercise was to create a program which produces that output. I must have spent at least an hour on it, and I came up with this:

```
def printMultiples(n):
 g = n*n
 m = n
 while m < g:
  if m%n == 0:
   print m, '\t',
   m = m+1
  elif m%n != 0:
   m = m+1
 print g

def uniqueTable(n, y):
 while n < y:
  printMultiples(n)
  n = n+1
 printMultiples(y)

uniqueTable(1, 7)
```

And it worked! I was so happy, I almost cried. Anyways, I've become addicted to these sorts of Python problems; currently I'm working on a program that prints the Fibonacci sequence. I go looking for problems, but they always go way over my head for some reason, for example the Facebook puzzles which use ASCII which I haven't studied yet. Does anyone know of any good Python problem sets?

Comment: www.codingbat.com has a number of warmup problems for Python.  www.learnpythonthehardway.org is a great tutorial with problems / challenges to work through.

Comment: A symbolic +1 for cracking the problem yourself! Unfortunately, this sort of question (asking for links) isn't really considered a good fit for SO. We'll be happy to help if you get mired on your next one, though.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, I won't ask for links again here.

Comment: **[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)** maintains a list of problems in increasing difficulty which can be solved in any language (Python included, of course). That should keep you busy for a while :)

Comment: Asking for links is fine. StackOverflow likes questions with a clear objective answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) is a great way to learn Python, plus it gives you exposure to quite a few libraries too.

Answer (score 2):

Cool exercise indeed, I learned a bit myself trying to come with an one line Python command to produce that output and here it is:

```
print "\n".join('\t'.join(str(x*i) for i in range(1,x+1)) for x in range(1,7+1))
```

Great way to learn Python!

Comment: you did not answered the question, +1 anyway for the code :)